Every point inside a convex polyhedron can be expressed as a convex combination of the vertices.
Consider a polyhedron $P$ in $\mathbb R^n$.
That is, $P$ is an intersection of linear inequalities and linear equations (in general, an intersection of linear inequalities) ;
$$P = \{x\in\mathbb R^n:Ax\le b\}$$
Suppose further that $P$ is bounded.
Let $v_1$, $\cdots$, $v_m$ be the vertices of $P$.
Prove that every point in $P$ can be expressed as a convex combination of $v_i$'s, or

For $p\in P$, there exist $a_1$, $\cdots$, $a_m$ such that
$$p=\sum_{i=1}^ma_iv_i$$
where $\sum_i a_i=1$ and $0\le a_i\le1$ for all $i$.

I found that the above statement is a direct consquence of Weyl-Minkowski theorem (theorem 2.5.1) or Krein–Milman theorem. But I suspect there exists an easier explanation.

Isn't it just Carathéodory's theorem?

The statement is not true when $P$ is unbounded, e.g. $P = [0, \infty)$ in dimension 1.

@nejimban According to your comment, I read An Easy Path to Convex Analysis and Applications In this book, Caratheodory theorem states "Every element $x$ in the convex hull $\text{co}\Omega$ of $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^n$ can be represented as a convex combination of no more than $n+1$ element of the set $\Omega$." So I can set $\Omega$ to be the set of vertices of $P$, and use the theorem, but only when $P=\text{co}\Omega$. Meaning, I have to ensure that polehedra is a convex hull of vertices.

@nejimban  This seems to reduce to the original question.

@gerw You're right. Bounding condition is omitted.

The case when $\boldsymbol{n=2}$.
Consider a triangle $\triangle v_1v_2v_3$.
Let $P$ be the union of $P$ and the interior of $P$.
Let $p\in P$.
Let $q$ be the intersection of the line $pv_1$ and $v_2v_3$.
Since $q$ lies between $v_2$ and $v_3$,
$$q = \lambda v_2+(1-\lambda)v_3$$
for some $0\le\lambda\le1$.Since $p$ lies between $v_1$ and $q$,
$$
\begin{align*}
p&=\mu v_1+(1-\mu)q\\
 &=\mu v_1+(1-\mu)\lambda v_2+(1-\mu)(1-\lambda)v_3\\
\end{align*}
$$
for some $0\le\mu\le1$. So $p$ is now a convex combination of $v_i$'s.
Now consider a polygon $P$ in $\mathbb R^2$. A point $p$ in $P$ resides in at least one triangle $\triangle v_1v_2v_3$ where $v_i$'s are vertices of $P$.
It follows that the above statement holds for two-dimensional case.
Possible Generalization
The above reasoning follows mainly from the fact that every polygon can be partitioned into triangles.
I can easily generalize it to $n=3$, since I can think of tetrahedrons instead of triangles. Since every polyhedron can be partitioned into tetrahedrons, The proof for $n=3$ is feasible.
If every n-dimensional polyhedron can be partitioned into simplexes, then the above statement holds without appealing to Weyl-Minkowski or Krein-Milman. Is this triangular partition holds in general?

How do you propose to show that a polyhedron is a union of simplices, without using or essentially proving Krein-Milman?
